# What does a question mark mean when reading a bit from a text file in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I'm using VIVADO as my simulator. I am trying to read a very simple input file that has 2 columns, the time and the value of a bit I'm trying to set. Here's the input file:

```
104 us 1
108 us 0
116 us 1
```

Type time takes in 2 columns one for the quantity the other for the resolution. For example the first line gives me "104 us". That part is actually working fine.

The problem is the "third" column (or second value) which is being assigned a '?' instead of '1', in case of the first line.

And the VHDL code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use std.textio.all;

entity tb_input_from_txt is
end tb_input_from_txt;

architecture rtl_tb_input_from_txt of tb_input_from_txt is

  constant file_name_c : string := "input_data.txt";
  signal clk_100M_s : std_logic := '0';
  signal reset_s : std_logic := '0'; 
  signal dig_s : bit;
  
  file fptr: text;
  --signal line_sig : line;

begin

  clk_100M_s <= not clk_100M_s after 5 ns;
  reset_s <= '0', '1' after 40 us;

  GetData_proc: process
     variable fstatus       : file_open_status;
     
     variable file_line     : line;
     variable timewhen_v    : time;
     variable value_set_v   : bit;
     variable ok            : boolean;
        
  begin
    wait until reset_s = '1';
    file_open(fstatus, fptr, file_name_c, read_mode);
    while (not endfile(fptr)) loop
      readline(fptr, file_line);
      read(file_line, timewhen_v, ok);
      assert ok
        report "Read 'wait_time' failed for line: " & file_line.all
        severity failure;
        
      read(file_line, value_set_v, ok);
      assert ok
        report "Read 'value_set_v' failed for line: " & file_line.all
        severity failure;
        
      wait for timewhen_v -  NOW;
        dig_s <= value_set_v;
    end loop;
    wait for 5 ns;
  end process GetData_proc;

end architecture rtl_tb_input_from_txt;
```

When I run this the **dig_s** signal starts having the value '?' (question mark) starting at 104 us. So I know the file is being read almost correct because the value of **dig_s** changes at 104 us like it's supposed to. But why am I getting the '?' value instead of the correct bit value?

Comment: THe code I provided is the testbench code. And yes I'm looking at the waveform. That's how I know the dig_s signal starts having the value '?'. I cannot find anything in the VIVADO  docs.

Comment: As you can see in the source code the first read is assigned a type "time". This "type" time takes in 2 columns one for the quantity the other for the resolution. For example the first line gives me "104 us". That part is actually working fine. The problem is the "third" column (or second value) which is being assigned a '?' instead of '1', in case of the first line.

Comment: Your comments could be part of the question. Your errant question mark(s) are not the fault of your VHDL code nor three values provided for input_data.txt. Using ghdl/gktwave I observe a '0' to '1' transaction on dig_s at 104 us. Type bit is an enumerated character type with two values, the enumerated value names '0' and '1' for positions 0 and 1 respectively. If I had to hazard a guess the the enumerated value name for '1' isn't found or has been damaged to make it unprintable. There might be concern to either Vivado version or integrity of the install may have been compromised.

Comment: This is likely a vivado bug. The bit type can only be 0 or 1, and not ?. No standard types in vhdl have ? As a legal value (other than character)

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a Vivado bug because if you switch the 2 columns like this:

```
1 104 us
0 108 us
1 116 us
```

and switch the two read statements in the code I have no problem anymore. For me this is an acceptable workaround.

Comment: It'd be beneficial if the bug were reported and acted on. This limits portability from other implementations as well as aesthetics. There's another thing you can try with the previous order in input_data.txt and read procedure call order. Using -2008 switch dig_s and value_set_v to std_logic, there's a read procedure in the -2008 package std_logic_1164 for std_logic.